# How do I validate an item that is being Added to property that is a collection?

Tags: c#, .net

Ok, we have the class Ticket that contains a property:

```
List<TaskComment> Comments;
```

I have it set up with a back property so that I can do some validation:

```
private List<TaskComment> _comments;
public List<TaskComment> Comment
{
   get
   { //stuff }
   internal set
   { //stuff }
}
```

Despite setting the set to internal, the Add() method is still exposed outside of the assembly. But regardless, what I want to do is set the ticketId property of a comment object as it is being added to the collection. For example:

```
var ticket = new TaskTicket();
var comment = new TaskComment { //initializers }
ticket.Comments.Add(comment);

--inside the ticket:
public List<TaskComment> Comments
{
   get{ //stuff }
   set
   {
      ((TaskComment)value).TicketId = this._ticketId;
   }
}
```

But this isn't working. It's telling me that it can't cast from TaskComment to MyLibrary.TaskComment. Which really doesn't make any sense to me. But besides that, this doesn't feel right anyway. So how exactly do I modify the incoming value/object before adding it to the class's collection?

Comment: Do you intend that the `set` for your List should add an item to the list? Because that's not what `set` does

Comment: Right, I understand that the setter is what allows me to set the full collection in one go

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Expose the `Collection` as readonly:

```
public IReadOnlyCollection<TaskComment> Comments
{
   get { return new ReadOnlyCollection(_comments); }
}
```

Using the previous implementation `_comments` is now exposed to the caller. To allow the client to add/remove items you'd implement `Add` and `Remove` members that add\remove from the internal list.

```
public void Add(Comment comment)
{
    /* code */
    _comments.Add(comment);
}

public void Remove(Comment comment)
{
    /* code */
    _comments.Remove(comment);
}
```

Alternatively, you could [implement your own](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y536ey6.aspx) `IList` providing the proper implementations for your `Add` and `Remove` methods.

Comment: Ok so in otherwords, I'm disabling the public setter, and then creating public methods to add the comment. And then just handle my business in there?

Comment: @Sinaesthetic not disabling, making it readonly, to where the only way to add/remove is through `Add(...)` and `Remove(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you can *limit* pubblicly esposed `List<T>` class. 
If you don't use the ponetial of the `List<T>` in your app too much, I would suggest to just wrap that list.

Say:

```
pulbic void AddComment(TaskComment task)
{
    /*Some validation on task parameter*/

    taskComments.Add(task);
}
```

and remove public `get` acessor from the `Comments` property, or entire property itself (**if* this is possible)

Answer (score 0):

The value object in your setter is going to be of type List so when you cast it to type TaskComment, it is throwing the error.  In your code you could just do

```
var comment = new TaskComment { //initializers } 
comment.TicketId = ticket.TicketId; //where TicketId is a public property for _ticketId
ticket.Comments.Add(comment);
```

Or you could overload the Add() method to add the comment to the Comment collection

Answer (score 0):

Keep the private field as a List, but change your property so that it's readonly and is IEnumerable. Then implement a specific Add method, as others have suggested, that accesses the private field. This way your callers can freely iterate over the collection but must use the add method to add to it, giving you a place to validate, etc and throw exceptions or return a success code.

Returning concrete collection types limits your options for future changes. Whereas, returning an interface allows you to change the underlying collection with no impact on the caller(s).

Newing up a ReadOnlyCollection seems wasteful when a List has implicit IEnumerable support.